# android list view footer is not displaying

Tags: android, android-listview

I am adding List Items to list view like

If I have 50 List Items, I am loading first 10 Items and then remaining 10 Items and so on...

You can find some portion of code here for reverence...

```
itemsPerPage=10;
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
 footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.footer, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView); 
adapter.addAll(getItemsBetween(0, itemsPerPage));// Loading first 10 Items
```

and Here is my Scrolling code...

```
 list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if (totalItemCount <= totalCount) {
                    // what is the bottom iten that is visible
                    int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                    if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount)){


                        int currentItemCount= mostViewdAdapter.getCount();

                        mostViewdAdapter.addAll(getItemsBetween(currentItemCount, currentItemCount+itemsPerPage));
                        mostViewdAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


                }else{
                    System.out.println("End of the list view reached");
                    footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }




        }
    });
```

Here I am sharing my footer XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/footerBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Loading..." />
```

Comment: did you set and visibility attributes to R.layout.footer in XML ?

Comment: Please try to set null adapter and check is footer is visible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Have a look at following code
    1) Add custom_listview_footer.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Invite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Load More"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

2) In your activity  call 
      View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) _con
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_listview_footer, null, false);
3) Call Button of the footer view
Button btnInvite = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Invite);

4) Lastly Add footer to the listview

lvPhnContacts.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more code about when you call `Listview.setAdapter()` ?
You should call `addFooterView()` before you set adapter to your listview.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code.

```
itemsPerPage=10;
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
 footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.footer, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView); 
adapter.addAll(getItemsBetween(0, itemsPerPage));// Loading first 10 Items
// after set footer
list.setAdapter(your adapter);//set adapter 


list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

       final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
       if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
           //load more data
           // footerView visible
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: but when I call the thread inside List Scrolling like http://pastebin.com/8yVm0ATP is working but why not the previous

Comment: its boz of u have add more data in listview which need thread to load more data.in your code you directly add data which cant reflect in ur listview boz of lots of work.